# Output each line of text (+ the first line) to its own .txt file VBS-Script

Tags: vbscript

I need a VBS script to output the first line of text along with another line of text for file data.txt.

example of my text.txt file

line1 + line2 to 1.txt
line1 + line3 to 2.txt
line1 + line4 to 3.txt

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
joe

Comment: Please post whatever code you already have for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time since i used VBS

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set src = fso.OpenTextFile("test.txt",1)
lines = split(src.readall,vbcrlf)

for i = 1 to ubound(lines)
 set dst = fso.CreateTextFile( i & ".txt", true)
 dst.writeline lines(0)
 dst.writeline lines(i)
 dst.close
next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to files using the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28VS.85%29.aspx). This page shows some sample code for opening and writing to a file: [Working with Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)